# Set dynamic IP address range for local switch

Tags: windows-10, networking, switch

I have a netgear GS342TP S350 switch. This is a local switch that's plugged directly in to my windows 10 computer. When I bought it, I was under the assumption that I could limit the range of IP addresses directly from that switch, but after getting off the phone with tech support, I've learned that this is an unmanaged switch.

Is there anyway I can have my PC limit the range of dynamic IP addresses that can be assigned? For reference, I'm trying to constrict everything to be between .110 and .124. The switch is plugged is directly plugged in to my PC, so there's nothing between it and the PC. Additionally, theres no need to connect this switch to the internet. Just communication between the PC and the devices attached to the switch.

Comment: I admit I am confused. Can't find "netgear GS342TP S350". Switches are usually not connected to computers, it is vice versa. Switches do not limit IPs. Where is your PC getting it's IP? You should probably limit the IPs on the DHCP server (if any connected). Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: If this device is truly just an unmanaged switch (I believe it is), then there is nothing to limit and nothing can be limited. Just connect devices to it and that will be the usage of the switch.

Comment: Use your router to limit dynamic DHCP addressing. A switch is just a through-port, it does nothing to the signal except pass it from any input to all outputs.

Answer (score 0):

A switch doesn't assign IP addresses. A DHCP server does (usually "included" in your router). You need to configure your DHCP server unless you don't have one then you need to set it up or assign IPs manually.